# Changing font in a description

Tags: fonts, lists, italic, description

How to change the font of some words of an item of a description?
I want it to appear like this:

**Abc *Def***
     Description...
**Ghi *Jkl***
     Description

So that the words *Def* and *Jkl* are italique.

The following code doesn't work as intended, as all words are regular:

```
\begin{description}
  \item[Abd \textit{Def}] \hfill \\ 
Description...
  \item[Ghi \textit{Jkl}] \hfill \\ 
Description...
\end{description}
```

Comment: Your example [works for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JtV54.png). Can you explain why this output isn't what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\normalfont` switch before `\textit`, or the `\textnormal` command, to "kill" the boldface font attribute; of course, you can define a dedicated command for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[description]{style=nextline}

\newcommand\MyIt[1]{{\normalfont\textit{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[Abd \MyIt{Def}]
Description...
  \item[Ghi \MyIt{Jkl}]
Description...
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

I used the `nextline` style from the `enumitem` package to give the descriptions on a new line.
[image]

Comment: I'm very tempted to edit your answer in order to remove the last remark. By the way, you're forgetting about `\textnormal`

Comment: @egreg Don't worry, I've removed it myself.